# CSS attributes auto organizer

Tags: css

I am looking for a site that can order all my css attributes instead

```
.class{ color:white; float:left; padding:10px; }
```

to give me the right order

```
.class{ float:left; padding:10px, color:white; }
```

In perfomance terms I won´t gain any advantage but I want to have it all organized if someone picks my project in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search gave me [StyleNeat](http://www.styleneat.com/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will save time if you write the code in the order you want from the beginning, instead of having to copy and paste the code each time in some "make-my-code-cool" thing.

Just write your code in a standardized way and in the order you want, possibly grouping the code in different sections based on your actual html markup, and maybe also ordered the same way as they appear in your html markup.